# laravel how to use force index in eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an SQL query that looks like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders FORCE INDEX(order_type_index) WHERE `type` = 1
```

I can use query builder to recreate this:

```php
DB::table(DB::raw('orders force index(orders_type_index)'))
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->get();
```

But is there anyway to make Eloquent use this index, like:

```php
Order::forceIndex('orders_type_index')->where('type', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Check: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/33

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by creating a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) that changes the builder's table name when applied. The table should be checked for the index before it's used. You could throw an exception or ignore it if an invalid index name is supplied (I chose the latter approach.)

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/*
 * Class Order
 *
 * @method \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder useIndex(string $index)
 * @method \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder forceIndex(string $index)
 */
class Order extends Model
{
    private function tableIndexExists(string $index): boolean
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();
        $index = strtolower($index);
        $indices = Schema::getConnection()
            ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
            ->listTableIndexes($table);

        return array_key_exists($index, $indices);
    }

    public function scopeUseIndex(Builder $query, string $index): Builder
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();

        return $this->tableIndexExists($index)
            ? $query->from(DB::raw("`$table` USE INDEX(`$index`)"))
            : $query;
    }

    public function scopeForceIndex(Builder $query, string $index): Builder
    {
        $table = $this->getTable();

        return $this->tableIndexExists($index)
            ? $query->from(DB::raw("`$table` FORCE INDEX(`$index`)"))
            : $query;
    }
}
```

If you need to do this on multiple models, it can easily be added to a trait and imported. The docblock ensures that your IDE is aware of the magic methods for code completion.

Then you can use it like this:

```php
$orders = Order::forceIndex("orders_type_index")->where("type", 1)->get();

// or this:
$orders = Customer::find(234)
    ->orders()
    ->forceIndex("orders_type_index")
    ->where("type", 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

https://packagist.org/packages/shaburov/laravel-mysql-index-hints-scope

```
Order::useIndex('test_index')
->ignoreIndex('test_index')
->useIndex(['test_index', 'example_index']);
```

Comment: Expanding this answer to explain what this package does and tailoring it to match the question would make it more helpful. Also note if you are self-promoting your own project, website, product, etc. you must declare this in the body of your post or it will be considered spam. Please edit your answer to include this information if needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31734550)