# Get Undefined method name exception in repository design pattern in laravel ( Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I have a repository that have this function inside it:

```
class MyRepository {

    public function findWhere(string $column, $operator = '=', $value = null)
    {
        return $this->entity->where($column, $operator, $value);
    }
}
```

Now in my controller, I want to use it to have many where functions:

for example this query :

```
Model::where('id','=',2)->where('name' , '=' , 'test')->get() 

= 
$repository = app(MyRepository::class);

$repository->findWhere('id', '=', 2)
            ->findWhere('name', '=', 'test')
            ->get();
```

but I get following error after running the above code:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::findWhere()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize Laravel's Database\Query\Builder (make better subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555025/how-to-customize-laravels-database-query-builder-make-better-subquery)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa no it  doesnt help me. because I dont want to ovrride Laravel classes and searching for another solution that implement in my repository class

Comment: Where are you initializing `$repository` variable? Can you edit that into your question please.

Comment: Try using macros: [Add custom function to Laravel query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069178/7376590)

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen yes I initialized it into serviceProvider. its right.         $this->app->singleton(RepositoryInterface::class , EloquentRepository::class); then in my controller injected RepositoryInterface

Comment: As the error suggests. It is trying to find out method named findWhere on Eloquent class and not your custom class. Something isn't working with the initialization as intended.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen the problem is findWhere method returns an object of type Builder and when I want to use another findWhere on this object it returns an exception that there is not this function on this object. I should use this function on repository object.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

we can have another method in Repository class that just add conditions and return $this.

for example:

```
public function chainWhere($column, $value)
{
   $this->entity->where($column, $value);

   return $this;
}
```

Now in controller we can have any number of where conditions that we want

just for latest where condition we should use findWhere because we need Builder object to have result
for example:

```
 $repository
      ->chainWhere('id', '=', 2)
      ->chainWhere('condition2', '=', 20)
      ->chainWhere('condition3', '=', 30)   
      ->findWhere('name', '=', 'test')
      ->get();
```

Comment: I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel with this. What benefit does this implementation have over the built-in query builder's  [`->where(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses) method?

Comment: Its just an excercise of Repository DP, I want to separate and transfer all database related codes to another class. and dont use query builder functions directly in controllers.